# Trouble installing local R library on docker

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I am trying to deploy my Shiny app on docker (using the rocker/shiny-verse:3.6.3 base image) but I'm facing issues when I try installing local (non-CRAN) packages via docker. The installation works fine when done within RStudio.

- Docker Engine v19.03.13
- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

### Success - When I try installing the local package within RStudio:

```
> install.packages("<FULLPATH>/customLibrary.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/p/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘customLibrary’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

---

### Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:3.6.3
RUN R -e "install.packages('<FULLPATH>/customLibrary.zip', repos = NULL, type = 'win.binary')"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('gtable', 'data.table', 'shinydashboard', 'ggplot2'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com', dependencies=FALSE)"
COPY . /srv/shiny-server
EXPOSE 3838
```

### Failure - When I build my Docker image using aforementioned Dockerfile:

```
[+] Building 0.8s (6/8)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 465B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/rocker/shiny-verse:3.6.3                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/rocker/shiny-verse:3.6.3                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 517B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [2/4] RUN R -e "install.packages('<FULLPATH>/customRLibrary.zip', repos = NULL, type = 'win.bin  0.7s
------
 > [2/4] RUN R -e "install.packages('<FULLPATH>/customRLibrary.zip', repos = NULL, type = 'win.binary')":
#5 0.599
#5 0.599 R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
#5 0.599 Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
#5 0.599 Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#5 0.599
#5 0.599 R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
#5 0.599 You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
#5 0.599 Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
#5 0.599
#5 0.599 R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
#5 0.599 Type 'contributors()' for more information and
#5 0.599 'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
#5 0.599
#5 0.599 Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
#5 0.599 'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
#5 0.599 Type 'q()' to quit R.
#5 0.599
#5 0.723 > install.packages('<FULLPATH>/customRLibrary.zip', repos = NULL, type = 'win.binary')
#5 0.728 Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
#5 0.728 (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
#5 0.728 Error in install.packages("<FULLPATH>/customRLibrary.zip",  :
#5 0.728   cannot install Windows binary packages on this platform
#5 0.728 Execution halted
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c R -e "install.packages('<FULLPATH>/customRLibrary.zip', repos = NULL, type = 'win.binary')"]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

---

Could someone point out where I'm going wrong? TIA.

Comment: You are trying to install a Windows binary package on Linux. This is what error is saying.

Comment: You need to build that library for Linux, this seem to be the easiest way to me. Sorry but can't help here as I'm not familiar with R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RStudio, where you develop your package, install devtools and then run

```
devtools::build(binary = FALSE)
```

It will produce a tar.gz package that can be installed on any platform.

Here's the documentation: https://rdrr.io/cran/devtools/man/build.html

Comment: RStudio has a More option where I built my library as a Source Package. That generated a tar.gz too. But when build my Dockerfile and try running the Shiny app, I get an error stating it could not find the library.

Is this the correct command to mention in the Dockerfile?

`RUN R -e "install.packages('<FULLPATH>/customLibrary.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"`

Answer (score 1):

The `rocker-org/shiny` dockerfile is build upon Debian.

> This is a Dockerfile for Shiny Server on Debian stable.

See on [GitHub](https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny) and on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny-verse) - [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny-verse/dockerfile) is the dockerfile.

This means that the comments to your OP are correct. You are trying to install a windows binary on a linux, which does not work. Consequently, your problem is here.

```
install.packages("<FULLPATH>/customLibrary.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

I guess that the solution is to compile your `customLibrary` for linux and simply do

```r
install.packages("<FULLPATH>/customLibrary.zip", repos = NULL)
```

Comment: I was able to install the package using the tar.gz source package option in RStudio. But now when I run the shiny app, I see an error as



`Warning: Error in library: there is no package called ‘customLibrary’

54: <Anonymous>

Error in library(pcrf) : there is no package called ‘customLibrary’`.  Is there a way for me to know if the installation worked fine?